# How to access node module documentation - eslint

Tags: node.js, npm, documentation, eslint

I'm working on a project that wraps ESLint output, and would like to access the content of the detailed markdown documentation for each warning. These files live in the ESLint repository at [docs/rules](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/tree/master/docs/rules).

However, it looks like the docs directory [might not get included](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/package.json#L24) in the packaged module, and so those docs might not be accessible from the standard product once installed.

The npm package.json docs also make it seem like docs may not typically be available:

```
directories.doc

Put markdown files in here. Eventually, these will be displayed

nicely, maybe, someday.
```

I'm new to working with node packages, so may be missing something obvious. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I dont understand your use case completely but why dont you link to the web page of each rule for docs? example: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle

Answer (score 0):

OP here. In the end, I worked with a friend on an ESLint fork that adds this functionality: https://github.com/codeclimate/eslint/commit/fb68870708b1b3bbad80a955eec085a8dfd5f13b

If anyone would like to use it, you can use our fork of eslint and access docs for each rules through:

`var docs = require("eslint").docs;`

where docs is an object with { rule_name: "content string....", ... }

complexity_readup = docs.get("complexity")